# Rails - Skipping one validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a rails program where I need to skip one step of validation, but that's it.  Is there a way to set up a validation so I can send in a param with object.valid? that tells the object to skip one validation.

This is what I have so far:

Model:

```
validates :event_id, :presence => true, :unless => :skip_event_id
```

Controller:

```
 if new_lot.valid(:skip_event_id => :true)?

          .
          .
          .
      end
```

This gives me a syntax error for the .valid.  I was just wondering if there is a way to make this work.  Thanks!

Note:  I still want all of my other validation to continue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set that variable before hand, it can't be checked on valid. Likewise, when using a method with a question mark you need to put the question mark before the parentheses.

Model:

```
attr_accessor :skip_event_id
```

Controller:

```
new_lot.skip_event_id = true
if new_lot.valid?
  # some stuff
end
```